# Polymer 2: custom validation with paper-input

Tags: polymer, behavior, polymer-2.x

I'm using a `paper-input` like this:

```
<paper-input 
    type="number" 
    allowed-pattern="[0-9,]"
    validator="my-validator"
    auto-validate="true"
    error-message="Invalid input!">
</paper-input>
```

I would like add my own logic to validate the input. I have searched info about that, but I only found Polymer 1.x examples. How do I add custom input validation in Polymer 2?

**EDIT:**

```
<paper-input 
    type="number" 
    allowed-pattern="[0-9,]"
    validator="my-validator1"
    auto-validate="true"
    value="{{value1}}"
    error-message="Invalid input!">
</paper-input>

<paper-input 
    type="number" 
    allowed-pattern="[0-9,]"
    validator="my-validator2"
    auto-validate="true"
    value="{{value2}}"
    error-message="Invalid input!">
</paper-input>

<paper-input 
    type="number" 
    allowed-pattern="[0-9,]"
    validator="my-validator3"   <!-- value1 + value 2 == value3 -->
    auto-validate="true"
    value="{{value3}}"
    error-message="Invalid input!">
</paper-input>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your usage of the validator looks correct, but the validator's definition is missing.

The key to adding the validator is to:

1. Define a template-less custom element that implements the [`Polymer.IronValidatorBehavior`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-validator-behavior) behavior.

   *Polymer 2.x:*

   ```
   class Foo extends Polymer.mixinBehaviors([Polymer.IronValidatorBehavior],
                                            Polymer.Element)
   {...}
   ```

   *Polymer 1.x:*

   ```
   Polymer({
     ...
     behaviors: [
       Polymer.IronValidatorBehavior
     ]
   });
   ```
2. In that element, define `validate(value)`, which returns a Boolean, indicating whether the `value` is valid.

Polymer 2.x example:

```
class SsnValidator extends Polymer.mixinBehaviors([Polymer.IronValidatorBehavior], Polymer.Element) {
  static get is() { return 'ssn-validator'; }

  ready() {
    super.ready();

    // Workaround https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-validator-behavior/issues/30#issuecomment-305643574
    new Polymer.IronMeta({type: 'validator', key: SsnValidator.is, value: this});
  }

  validate(value) {
    const re = /^\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4}$/;
    return re.test(value);
  }
}

window.customElements.define(SsnValidator.is, SsnValidator);
```

Note `ready()` uses a workaround for a [known issue with `IronValidatorBehavior` in Polymer 2](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-validator-behavior/issues/30). Alternatively, you could define the validator with the Polymer 1.x syntax (still supported in Polymer 2):

```
Polymer({
  is: 'ssn-validator',

  behaviors: [
    Polymer.IronValidatorBehavior
  ],

  validate: function(value) {
    const re = /^\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4}$/;
    return re.test(value);
  }
});
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/KqKjBK?editors=1010)

Comment: Thank you @tony19, your answer is pretty good but it does not work when I need to check if the third `paper-input` is equal to first `paper-input` plus second `paper-input`. I get `undefined` value when I try to get first and second value. I am going to edit my question to show that.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** The bug is resolved and works version 2.1.0

The custom validators doesn't work with polymer 2.0 class based structure. There is a bug about report here: https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-validator-behavior/issues/30

A workaround is not to use the `IronValidatorBehavior` and add the following line to the `connectedCallback()` function:

```
  class PasProfilePasswordValidator extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() {return 'pas-profile-password-validator';}
...
connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    new Polymer.IronMeta({type: 'validator', key: PasProfilePasswordValidator.is, value: this});
  }
```